# Optimal storage structure in Redis

Tags: data-structures, nosql, redis

I'm looking to store the follow group of information.  I store a minute timestamp(e.g. group all browserIDs seen in a 1 minute window) and then a list of browser references.  I'd like to be able have only one instance of a browser id

What data structure in Redis can I use for this data structure? Is there a more optimal way to store it?

```
...
12:06 -> browser1, browser7
12:07 -> browser8
12:08 -> browser4, browser5, browser6, browser9
...
```

Each row can have a time to live of about 1 day.

When adding a new browserID I'm first checking to see if the browser id already exists somewhere in the data if so delete and add to new minute row.

Lastly every 1 minute I take the row from 30 minutes ago and process those browserIDs and then remove that row from the list when fully processed.

There could be up to 1 million browser referenes in this data structure at any one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, new information, new answer :)

Let's make each browser a key in the database, pointing to which timestamp it's currently in. And also a key for each timestamp, with a set of which browsers it "contains".

When a new browser is added;

1. Check if it's already in the system by checking if its key exists.
2. If it is, check which timestamp it belongs to, remove it from the old time stamp, add it to the new one. Update the browser key.
3. If not, add it to the time stamp and set the browser key.

To expire the keys I would probably not use the built in expire, instead use a cron job or something to

1. Remove all browser keys in the timestamp
2. Remove the timestamp key.

Example data structure;

```
ts:12:01 -> {1, 3}
ts:12:02 -> {2}

browser:1 -> 12:01
browser:2 -> 12:02
browser:3 -> 12:01
```

This should be reasonably O(1), but with a slightly higher constant time (multiple requests for each operation). Could be reduced by using server side ruby scripting possibly.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

List is enough. In fact, if the number of browser is less than 400(according to your conf file, but default 400), Redis implements a sequential array to substitude list for space-efficient.

For more infomation : https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/ziplist.h

Comment: At any one time there could be up to 1 million browsers. hence the reason I have the data grouped they way I do. The idea being when I pull the query to get all people who were active in a given minute I get a list of browser ids back quickly.

Comment: I think you should store all browsers by hash table ahead for speeding up the query because your browser is too large. O(1) is great.

Comment: I've update the question to remove the concept of client id to make it clearer for now. So based on the change above what redis storage set is most applicable. If I need more than one data structure that is fine too.

Comment: I see what you mean by creating a index table by browser as well. double the space but O(1) queries for both.